# cambiar de estado al superar la columna de la fecha

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema: Necesito cambiar los estados despues de una fecha limite (tabla **fecha** columna **fecha**) y que al mismo tiempo se cambien los estados donde se referencia el **iddocumento** (incluyendo el de la tabla **documento**),

Esta es mi tabla **documento**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla **fecha**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla **movimiento**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este codigo logro cambiar el estado de la tabla **fecha**

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
CREATE EVENT verificar_tramite
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO
UPDATE fecha f
set f.estado='INACTIVO' 
where f.fecha <= NOW();
```

Pero no se como podria obtener el iddocumento y aplicarlo en las demas tablas, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: donde conectas las tres tablas del id (documento) con el iddocumento de las otras dos, sin conexión sea consulta select, update o lo que sea no vas a tener ninguna respuesta masomenos válida¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sabía que se podía, pero parece que MySQL es capaz de poner al día los valores de más de una tabla a la vez usando una sola sentencia `UPDATE`. Prueba la siguiente sentencia `UPDATE`:

```
update fecha f
  left join documento d
    on d.id = f.iddocumento
  left join movimiento m
    on m.iddocumento = f.iddocumento
  set f.estado = 'INACTIVO',
      d.estado = 'INACTIVO',
      m.estado = 'INACTIVO'
 where f.fecha <= now()
   and f.estado = 'ACTIVO'
```

Y nota que le agregué una condición adicional `f.estado = 'ACTIVO'` para evitar de volver a poner al día los registros que ya han sido marcados `INACTIVO`.

*(Una pequeña advertencia: El hecho de que tengas que modificar una misma columna `estado` en 3 tablas a la vez probablemente indica que tu modelo no está bien normalizado. Si todavía puedes hacerle correcciones, tal vez sería mejor si la columna `estado` la defines en una sola de las tablas.)*